# Как корректно сверстать страницу чата на мобильной версии?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу понять как правильно сверстать страницу чата для мобильной версии
Где сверху хедер, посередине сама переписка и снизу закрепленный инпут
Оно как бы вроде просто звучит, но на деле инпут снизу может увеличиваться если ввести много текста, до определенной высоты
И соответственно уже отправленные сообщения выше при увеличении инпута также должны подниматься (то есть просто position: fixed не покатит)
И само собой при нажатии на инпут с телефона у нас вылезает клавиатура, то есть инпут должен быть в зоне видимости (над клавиатурой)

То что имеется: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-pine-gtuwf
На телефоне [футер не показывается](https://gtuwf.csb.app):

PS Из рабочих примеров того что мне нужно нашел только vk. В мобильной версии vk сделано именно так как мне нужно, но не ясно как.

Comment: Вроде грид позволит такое сделать? Для хеадера даем auto, для боди 1fr, для блока с инпутом auto.

Comment: хм, спасибо
сейчас попробую

Comment: Увы не получилось(

Comment: К сожалению кодом помочь не могу ибо с телефона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroll">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так.
Чтобы на грид не переделывать, на флексе кое что добавить можно.
В .chat добавил `justify-content: space-between;`
В .chat__content добавил `flex: 1 1 auto;`
Вместо textarea сделал div c атрибутом contenteditable.
https://jsfiddle.net/sqxgphLj/

Comment: Но ведь с телефона футер по прежнему не виден